# How can I suspend|hibernate for certain time

Tags: suspend, laptop, hibernate

I try to give a behavior to a closing lid of a laptop following this rules:

> When the lid is closed:
>
> 1. After 1m, it should be screenlocked ;
> 2. After 10m, it should be suspended ;
> 3. After 15m, it should be shutdown.

So, I make the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
USER=fauve
 

sleep 1m
# set screensaver
su -c  "$HOME/.local/bin/screenlock" - $USER

# hibernate
sleep 9m
systemctl suspend


sleep 5m
# shutdown
shutdown 0
```

But as you see, the `shutdown` comes when the laptop is under suspension, so it will never shutdown.

So how can I program a suspension or shutdown for 5min, and then make the script keep going to shutdown completely the computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in short: you can't. At least not in software. When you put your computer in suspend, it's suspended. Software like `sleep` (or more precisely, the systick or timer that tells your kernel to wake up the task after a given time) simply won't run.

So, only thing here is a hardware solution. Your laptop needs to have some alarm clock to wake up, and come out of suspend!

Luckily, that's fairly standard;

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
echo `date '+%s' -d "+ 5 minutes"` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
systemctl suspend
systemctl shutdown
```

would do that. IF your laptop supports it.

Note that I doubt the sense in this. The way you wrote your script, your laptop *always* directly shuts down when it comes out of suspend after 5 minutes or longer. I think you want something else. My guess is you'd want to check whether the 5 minutes have actually passed and if they haven't, assume the laptop was manually brought out of suspend and *not* shut it down. In that case, you'd need to save the pre-suspend time, and compare it to the time after.

Maybe you want `systemctl suspend-then-hibernate`? That would seem a likely thing. Under the hood, it does the same: rely on the RTC to come out of suspend at some time, then save the system state to disk and power off *unless* manually woken up before.

Comment: 1. Fortunately, my laptop support wakealarm, I just test it :)
2. my laptop will not shutdown if it detect any activity in the 15min after the lid close because the whole script is interrupted if I activate my laptop. 
3. `systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` will hibernate and not poweroff. But is the battery consumption of hibernate is the same as poweroff ? And how to set time between suspend and hibernate ?

Comment: hibernate == poweroff with storage of RAM to disk/ssd and restoration on boot. It is the same power use.